# flink parsing JSON in map: InvalidProgramException: Task not serializable

Tags: scala, serialization, jackson, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am working a on Flink project and would like to parse the source JSON string data to Json Object.  I am using [jackson-module-scala](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala) for the JSON parsing. However, I encountered some issues with using the JSON parser within Flink APIs (`map` for example).

Here are some examples of the code, and I cannot understand the reason under the hood why it is behaving like this.

## Situation 1:

In this case, I am doing what the [jackson-module-scala's official exmaple code told me to do](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala#usage):

1. create a new `ObjectMapper`
2. register the `DefaultScalaModule`

   > *`DefaultScalaModule` is a Scala object that includes support for all currently supported Scala data types.*
3. call the `readValue` in order to parse the JSON to `Map`

The error I got is: `org.apache.flink.api.common.InvalidProgramException:`**`Task not serializable`**.

```
object JsonProcessing {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    // set up the execution environment
    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment

    // get input data
    val text = env.readTextFile("xxx")

    val mapper = new ObjectMapper
    mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
    val counts = text.map(mapper.readValue(_, classOf[Map[String, String]]))

    // execute and print result
    counts.print()

    env.execute("JsonProcessing")
  }

}
```

## Situation 2:

Then I did some Google, and came up with the following solution, where `registerModule` is moved into the `map` function.

```
val mapper = new ObjectMapper
val counts = text.map(l => {
  mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
  mapper.readValue(l, classOf[Map[String, String]])
})
```

However, what I am not able to understand is: **why this is going to work, with calling method of outside-defined object `mapper`?** Is it because the `ObjectMapper` itself is Serializable as stated here [ObjectMapper.java#L114](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.java#L114)?

Now, the JSON parsing is working fine, but every time, I have to call `mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)` which I think could cause some performance issue (***Does it?***). I also tried another solution as follows.

## Situation 3:

I created a new `case class Jsen`, and use it as the corresponding parsing class, registering the Scala modules. And it is also working fine.

However, this is not so flexible if your input JSON is varying very often. It is not maintainable to manage the class `Jsen`.

```
case class Jsen(
  @JsonProperty("a") a: String,
  @JsonProperty("c") c: String,
  @JsonProperty("e") e: String
)

object JsonProcessing {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    ...
    val mapper = new ObjectMapper
    val counts = text.map(mapper.readValue(_, classOf[Jsen]))
    ...

}
```

Additionally, I also tried using `JsonNode` without calling `registerModule` as follows:

```
    ...
    val mapper = new ObjectMapper
    val counts = text.map(mapper.readValue(_, classOf[JsonNode]))
    ...
```

It is working fine as well.

My main question is: **what is actually causing the problem of *Task not serializable* under the hood of `registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)`?**

How to identify whether your code could potentially cause this unserializable problem during coding?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thing is that Apache Flink is designed to be distributed. It means that it needs to be able to run your code remotely. So it means that all your processing functions should be serializable. In the current implementation this is ensure early on when you build your streaming process even if you will not run this in any distributed mode. This is a trade-off with an obvious benefit of providing you feedback down to the very line that breaks this contract (via exception stack trace).

So when you write

```
val counts = text.map(mapper.readValue(_, classOf[Map[String, String]]))
```

what you actually write is something like

```
val counts = text.map(new Function1[String, Map[String, String]] {
    val capturedMapper = mapper

    override def apply(param: String) = capturedMapper.readValue(param, classOf[Map[String, String]])
})
```

The important thing here is that you capture the `mapper` from the outside context and store it as a part of your `Function1` object that has to be serializble. And this means that the `mapper` has to be serializable. The designers of Jackson library recognized that kind of a need and since there is nothing fundamentally non-serizliable in a mapper they made their `ObjectMapper` and the default `Module`s serializable. Unfortunately for you the designers of Scala Jackson Module missed that and made their `DefaultScalaModule` deeply non-serialiazable by making [`ScalaTypeModifier`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/scala/modifiers/ScalaTypeModifier.scala) and all sub-classes non-serializable. This is why your second code works while the first one doesn't: "raw" `ObjectMapper` is serializable while `ObjectMapper` with pre-registered `DefaultScalaModule` is not.

There are a few possible workarounds. Probably the easiest one is to wrap `ObjectMapper`

```
object MapperWrapper extends java.io.Serializable {
  // this lazy is the important trick here
  // @transient adds some safety in current Scala (see also Update section)
  @transient lazy val mapper = {
    val mapper = new ObjectMapper
    mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
    mapper
  }

  def readValue[T](content: String, valueType: Class[T]): T = mapper.readValue(content, valueType)
}
```

and then use it as

```
val counts = text.map(MapperWrapper.readValue(_, classOf[Map[String, String]]))
```

This `lazy` trick works because although an instance of `DefaultScalaModule` is not serializable, the function to create an instance of `DefaultScalaModule` is.

---

**Update: what about @transient?**

> what are the differences here, if I add `lazy val` vs. `@transient lazy val`?

This is actually a tricky question. What the `lazy val` is compiled to is actually something like this:

```
object MapperWrapper extends java.io.Serializable {

  // @transient is set or not set for both fields depending on its presence at "lazy val" 
  [@transient] private var mapperValue: ObjectMapper = null
  [@transient] @volatile private var mapperInitialized = false

  def mapper: ObjectMapper = {
    if (!mapperInitialized) {
      this.synchronized {
        val mapper = new ObjectMapper
        mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
        mapperValue = mapper
        mapperInitialized = true
      }
    }
    mapperValue
  }


  def readValue[T](content: String, valueType: Class[T]): T = mapper.readValue(content, valueType)
}
```

where `@transient` on the `lazy val` affects both backing fields. So now you can see why `lazy val` trick works:

1. locally it works because it delays initialization of the `mapperValue` field until first access to the `mapper` method so the field is safe `null` when the serialization check is performed
2. remotely it works because `MapperWrapper` is fully serializable and the logic of how `lazy val` should be initialized is put into a method of the same class (see `def mapper`).

Note however that AFAIK this behavior of how `lazy val` is compiled is an implementation detail of the current Scala compiler rather than a part of the Scala specification. If at some later point a class similar to .Net [`Lazy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331(v=vs.110).aspx) will be added to the Java standard library, Scala compiler potentially might start generating different code. This is important because it provides a kind of trade-off for `@transient`. The benefit of adding `@transient` now is that it ensures that code like this works as well:

```
val someJson:String = "..."
val something:Something = MapperWrapper.readValue(someJson:String, ...)
val counts = text.map(MapperWrapper.readValue(_, classOf[Map[String, String]]))
```

Without `@transient` the code above will fail because we forced initialization of the `lazy` backing field and now it contains a non-serializable value. With  `@transient` this is not an issue as that field will not be serialized at all.

A potential drawback of `@transient` is that if Scala changes the way code for `lazy val` is generated and the field is marked as `@transient`, it might actually be not de-serialized in the remote-work scenario.

Also there is a trick with `object` because for `object`s Scala compiler generates custom de-serialization logic (overrides [`readResolve`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html)) to return the same singleton object. It means that the object including the `lazy val` is not really de-serialized and the value from the `object` itself is used. It means that `@transient lazy val` inside `object` is much more future-proof than inside `class` in remote scenario.

Comment: One additional question: at the end, you were saying the `lazy val` works. I would like to know, what are the differences here, if I add `lazy val` vs. `@transient lazy val`?

Comment: @ChangLiu, I've added an update to answer this question. Hope this clarifies things.

Comment: So, this looks like for a consumer. Is there a similar pattern for a Producer/SerializationSchema?

Comment: Can I use this way for checking the data types of the extracted `JSON` attributes using `ObjectNode`?