# Deserializing FlinkKafkaProducer's events from Kafka topic results in empty JSON records

Tags: json, serialization, apache-kafka, deserialization, apache-flink

**EDIT**
I prepared minimal reproducible example https://github.com/kazuhirokomoda/flink-kafka-druid

I have a data pipeline and code, exactly the same (unless otherwise noted at the bottom of this post) as mentioned in my previous question: [In what binary format should I ingest Kafka topic to Druid, whose events are sent from FlinkKafkaProducer[<Scala case class>]?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68675342/9728653) Basically I am using Jackson's `ObjectMapper` within custom `KafkaSerializationSchema` (i.e. `ExampleDataSerializationSchema`) to serialize events.

For testing purpose, I prepared Kafka 2.6 on a bare metal server, following https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart

I used `kafka-console-consumer.sh` to inspect what are sent from Flink job to Kafka topic, but I only saw empty JSON records, while I was expecting non-empty records.

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --topic <topic> --from-beginning --bootstrap-server localhost:9092
...
{}
{}
{}
^CProcessed a total of 287 messages
```

### Note

- Not surprisingly, following [The Kafka quickstart](https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart) from STEP 1 up to STEP 5: READ THE EVENTS (i.e.string input/output with Kafka console producer/consumer) worked fine.
- Sending (fixed) string (instead of Jackson/JSON) from Flink job also worked fine. (See code below)

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --topic <topic> --from-beginning --bootstrap-server localhost:9092
...
fixed string to send to kafka
fixed string to send to kafka
fixed string to send to kafka
^CProcessed a total of 287 messages
```

### Questions

- When using custom serializer (i.e. Flink's `ExampleDataSerializationSchema` as shown in my previous question [In what binary format should I ingest Kafka topic to Druid, whose events are sent from FlinkKafkaProducer[<Scala case class>]?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68675342/9728653)), do I need to define custom **de**serializer as well ?

  - If yes, how can I implement it and where can I place it so Kafka console consumer (and eventually Druid, which is the goal of my previous question) can use it?
- Is serialization, or deserialization to be blamed for the records being empty, or both?
- In terms of (JSON) serialization/deserialization, is there any difference between Kafka 0.11.x and 2.x, that need to be taken care of ?
- Is there any alternative of Jackson if I want to serialize/deserialize events as JSON?

Thank you again for your help.

### Code

#### Flink -> Kafka

```
object KafkaSink {
  def sendToKafka(exampleDataStream: DataStream[ExampleData], props: ParameterTool): DataStreamSink[ExampleData] = {
    // defined in my previous question
  }

  // just for testing
  def sendToKafkaString(exampleDataStream: DataStream[ExampleData], props: ParameterTool): DataStreamSink[String] = {
    val topic: String = ...
    val properties: Properties = ... 

    val producer = new FlinkKafkaProducer[String](
      topic,
      new ExampleDataStringSerializationSchema(topic),
      properties,
      FlinkKafkaProducer.Semantic.EXACTLY_ONCE)

    val exampleDataStreamString = exampleDataStream.map(_ => "fixed string to send to kafka")
    exampleDataStreamString.addSink(producer)
  }
}
```

```
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets

class ExampleDataStringSerializationSchema(topic: String) extends KafkaSerializationSchema[String]{
  override def serialize(element: String, timestamp: java.lang.Long): ProducerRecord[Array[Byte], Array[Byte]] = {
    new ProducerRecord[Array[Byte], Array[Byte]](topic, element.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
  }
}
```

Comment: console consumer just reads strings, so its not doing JSON deserialization... For the producer, `mapper.writeValueAsBytes` was correct, why did you change it? You appear to have been getting an error in `case e: JsonProcessingException => ` and not logging it, so you get an empty byte array / object

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I didn't mean to change, just wanted to check string can work.
I will try logging next (took more time than I expected), but just wanted to share that I prepared minimal reproducible example here https://github.com/kazuhirokomoda/flink-kafka-druid

Comment: In your error there, you're running into Scala/Flink issues on how tasks get serialized.... Some details [about that here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48379663/flink-parsing-json-in-map-invalidprogramexception-task-not-serializable). Basically, the issue is that the `ObjectMapper` needs to be defined "somewhere else" rather than in the class body. Note that you could try to copy [the old JSON serialization schema](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/release-1.7.2/flink-formats/flink-json/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/formats/json/JsonRowSerializationSchema.java)

Comment: Thank you, the link helped me a lot! At least for my wordcount example repo, the wrapper workaround worked fine https://github.com/kazuhirokomoda/flink-kafka-druid/pull/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ObjectMapper wrapper workaround worked for me.

https://github.com/kazuhirokomoda/flink-kafka-druid/pull/1

Thank you [onecricketeer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2308683/onecricketeer)!